# Test for compatibility in Matlab

Tags: matlab, compatibility, simulink, backwards-compatibility, stateflow

I'm working with an open source Matlab toolbox which, according to its creators, is compatible for versions of Matlab over 7.6, i.e., R2008a.  I tried to run it in R2011b and it threw the exception: Undefined variable "Simulink" or class "Simulink.Mask.create"

Since:
1- Simulink is installed and functional in this R2011b;
2- I have already run the same code in a R2014b successfully;
I conclude that this is a problem of compatibility -In contrast to their claim, their code is compatible for some version later than R2011b-.

I wish I could contribute with them by directly telling them, not only that their code is not compatible with Matlab 7.6, but also the earliest version in which the statement associated with Simulink.Mask.create would run.

So, in precise terms, MY QUESTION IS: Given a command, built-in function, namespace resolution sequence, or whatever feature that I can find in some version of Matlab, what is the way of knowing what is the earliest version in which that feature is active?

I have tried http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/release-notes.html which is not searchable or navigable the way I wish it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem. [This page](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/152699) talks of the same problem - claiming that there is no good solution... It does however come with a smart way of searching through the release notes:

1. Click on the bottommost unexpanded release, to expand the it.
2. Click on "expand all" all link to expand all link just below.
3. If any unexpanded releases remain goto 1.
4. Now use the browser search functionality (often ctrl+f) to search the fully expanded page.

Good luck!

**EDIT:**
To see older releases too you need to start with the following step:

0: Click the link in the bottom saying "View release notes for older releases".

And then continue like above.

Comment: Right! doing this I found that Simulink.Mask was introduced in R2012b.  However, the release notes site goes back not earlier than R2011b!

Comment: True, I missed that one.  That link goes back to the releases in 2005 and not older, while the first release of Matlab was in 1984.  Well, from what I see in Wikipedia, it is quite unlikely that someone has to deal with compatibility problems from those old versions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a straightforward way to find what you want.
In my opinion you have to do it manually for each version of MATLAB
in order to find is certain feature supported or not.
Some feature may be obsolete or  may exist a bug.
So the best way to do is :
A) Look at particular version of relase notes, for example ,let say R2011a
  New Features, Bug Fixes, Compatibility Considerations
  click on "expand all", then use find "your keyword" in your browser
  ( be careful about case sensitivity)

You also have "Compatibility Summary", search it, too.

B) If something is very important and you are sure there is an issue
   just email to customer service and ask for further steps
   and who may contact further.